# R: match values in dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, match

I have the following list of dataframes:

```
a<-data.frame(
  Data0=c("Y","Y","Y","Y","Y","Y","N","N","N","N","N","N"),
  Data1=c(16,18,19,20,21,50,16,18,19,20,21,50),
  Data2=c(2.2291,2.0743,1.9369,1.8148,1.7064,1.6102,2.2291,2.0743,1.9369,1.8148,1.7064,1.6102)
)
b<-data.frame(
  Data0=c(-2 , 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 ,10 ,11) ,
  Data1=c(0.8891 ,0.8891,0.9051,1,0.8891,0.8891,0.7907,0.8891,0.9929,0.8891,0.8891,0.8891,0.8891)
)
dfl<-list(a,b)
```

I would like to make a function, for each of the dataframes in the list, that returns the numbers in the last column, for the matching variables in the previous columns.

For *a*, if I send "Y" and 16, I want 2.2291 and for *b*, if I send 5 I want 0.7907. The problem for *a* is that if I send a number smaller than 16, for either "Y" or "N", I want it to return the value as if it were 16, without manipulating the input variable. I manage to do this for *b*, but for *a*, where I have a "split" between "Y" and "N", I don't know how to solve this.

So far:

```
get_value<-function(vector){
  if (length(vector)==1) {
    from<-append(head(unlist(dfl[[2]][1],use.names=FALSE),-1),-9999,0)
    to  <-unlist(dfl[[2]][1],use.names=FALSE)

    match_from<-vector > from
    match_to<-vector <=to

    pos<-which(match_from==match_to)
    return(unlist(dfl[[2]][pos,2]))
  }
  else{
    print("not sure what to do for a")
  }
}
get_value(4)
get_value(-44)
```

The solution needs to take into account that sometimes for *a*, the columns Data0 and Data1 have switched places.

**EDIT**:
 input/output table:

```
INPUT       OUTPUT

c("Y",13) -->   2.2291

c("Y",50) -->   1.6102

c("N",20) -->   1.8148

c("N",50) -->   1.6102

c(-44))   -->     0.8891
```

Comment: I don't get the list since your data frames are so different. Will you specify in the function which data frame in the list to look in? Or does the function need to try them all.

Comment: Some sample input and output in a table would be very helpful. What if you send "Y" 18 to a, or "N" 18? What do you send to b, just a number like 6? Do you also send the "a" or "b"?

Comment: @Gregor: you can specify beforehand which dataframe you want, but I would like the same function to work for both dataframes, if that makes sense.

Comment: "can" makes it sound optional - which adds complexity. Please give an input/output table. Also, if you've solved the problem for `b`, show that code so we can better understand what you've done!

Comment: @Gregor: Ok, two sec! :)

Comment: @Gregor: Ok, I've posted what I've done so far. Dont laugh! :)

Comment: Okay, but also as I requested twice, please post an input/output table. And address the multiple data frames issue in that table (either the user inputs the data frame always, or sometimes, or never). Always is the easiest solution. If sometimes or never, you'll have to specify logic for how the function knows which data frame is the right one.

Comment: @Gregor: sorry, I forgot that! Yes, always, implicitly by what you give as input to the function: if you have a vector with length two, you want dataframe *a*. **EDIT**: So that I'm not misunderstanding, you want me to give you input and output? Just a copy of the data.frames, in a table, that is?

Comment: @Gregor: ok, input output table above! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate approach using `tidyverse` functions could be as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

get_value<-function(vector){
  if (length(vector)==1) 
  { df <- dfl[[2]]
    k <- df %>%
      arrange(Data0)%>%
      filter(Data0 >= vector) %>%
      select(Data1) %>%
      head(1)
  }
  else
  {df <- dfl[[1]]
  k <- df %>%
    arrange(Data0)%>%
    filter(Data0 == vector[1]) %>%
    filter(Data1 >= vector[2]) %>%
    select(Data2) %>%
    head(1)
  }
  return(k)
}
```

and test some outputs as:

```
> get_value(c(-44))
   Data1
1 0.8891
> get_value(c('N',16))
   Data2
1 2.2291
> get_value(c('Y',16))
   Data2
1 2.2291
> get_value(c('N',12))
   Data2
1 2.2291
> get_value(c('Y',11))
   Data2
1 2.2291
> get_value(c('Y',18))
   Data2
1 2.0743
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It looks very clean! I'll sit down and understand what you have done later today :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally figured out a way, but it is not so elegant, so help would be appreciated.

```
get_value<-function(vector){
  if (length(vector)==1) {
    from<-append(head(unlist(dfl[[2]][1],use.names=FALSE),-1),-9999,0)
    to  <-unlist(dfl[[2]][1],use.names=FALSE)

    match_from<-vector > from
    match_to<-vector <=  to

    pos<-which(match_from==match_to)
    return(unlist(dfl[[2]][pos,2]))
  }
  else{

    pos_1<-which(unlist(dfl[[1]][1],use.names=FALSE)==vector[1])

    from<-append(head(as.numeric(unlist(dfl[[1]][2],use.names=FALSE))[pos_1],-1),-9999,0)
    to  <-as.numeric(unlist(dfl[[1]][2],use.names=FALSE))[pos_1]

    match_from<-as.numeric(vector[2]) > from
    match_to  <-as.numeric(vector[2]) <=to
    pos<-pos_1[match_from == match_to]
    return(unlist(dfl[[1]][pos,3]))
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems very reasonable.

Comment: Well, thank you! Maybe not beautiful, but I'll take reasonable :)